# Exceptions and Error 404 when using StatsManager

Tags: c#, multithreading, xbox-live

Okay I tried to play a little bit with the StatsManager but I always got an exception trying to use anything with it when comes to

- Set a stat
- Get a stat

Because I doubted myself I had the idea just to use the UWPIntegration sample that is on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-api-csharp/tree/master/Tests/IntegrationTests/UWP/UWPIntegration) . I also added the Leaderboard items to my own project so the code works with my test sandbox. Logging in works as it should just StatsManager causes the issues.

[image]

But as with my own code I just get the same error / exception which is the following. I assume there is a bug in the code provided or the service configuration is not working as intended.

> System.AggregateException occurred   HResult=0x80131500   Message=One or more errors occurred.   Source=   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   Microsoft.Xbox.Services.XboxLiveHttpRequest.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<GetResponseWithAuth>b__1(Task`1
>   getResponseTask) in
>   D:\Data\VisualStudio\Projects\xbox-live-api-csharp\Source\api\XboxLiveHttpRequest.cs:line
>   117    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>
> Inner Exception 1: AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>
> Inner Exception 2: WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   (404) Not Found.

*Issue was found. My service.config used a wrong parameter name, see below in the comments of the solution.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different reasons why this might be the case. Not surprisingly, it means the cloud can't find the stat you've requested.

If you use Fiddler, you can capture the call and share with me the correlationID header. If you don't know Fiddler, let me know and I can help you.

However, some ideas off the top of my head

1. Make sure that you're in development mode - your sandbox is the one from the dev center site. If you aren't sure, you can use the [Windows Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-desktop) to see what your sandbox is - just click on Xbox Live in the left hand navigation.
2. Make sure you have hit "Test" on the dev center page where you defined your featured stats and leaderboards.
3. Make sure you are requesting the stat by the ID name you specified in the config window, not the display name.

Comment: I am not familiar with Fiddler so I may need some help. Regarding the points you listed: All of them I made. 1) I used SwitchSandbox.cmd to redirect to my Sandbox 2) I hit "Test" several times and got "Success" and 3) I used the ID strings (I created the last 2 to support the test app on github)

Comment: You can use the following to get started with Fiddler: [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/xbox/docs/xboxlive/using-xbox-live/troubleshooting/how-to-set-up-fiddler-for-debugging) Then look for the call to xboxlive.com that is returning the 404. Make sure you are on the "Inspectors" tab and then the RAW tab under that. You can copy and paste the full REQUEST and RESPONSE bodies and post them here.

Comment: Providing the Service Configuration Id for your product can also help us narrow down the search.  Look for the ServiceConfigurationId property in your XboxServices.config file.

Comment: I found the issue. It was a mistake on my side. In the services.config file I used `PrimaryServiceConfigId` instead of `ServiceConfigurationId`. Changed that and the Test is now running without exception. Maybe I used an older example for the services.config as a template. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, we're aware of that configuration file issue.  It's actually already been changed to PrimaryServiceConfigId to match the name used by the C++ version so when we release and update it will be changing back to be consistent.  That update just hasn't been released yet.