# Error 404 when using Xbox Live SDK Leaderboards

Tags: c#, uwp, monogame, xbox, xbox-live

I’ve built a game (C#, UWP, Monogame) and want to integrate it with Xbox Live SDK (`Microsoft.Xbox.Live.SDK.WinRT.UWP` from NuGet).

Already got auth working but experiencing some problems with `StatisticManager`/`Leaderboard`.

What exactly am I doing:

1. Add user with `StatisticManager.AddLocalUser(user)` and wait for `StatisticEventType.LocalUserAdded` event from `DoWork`
2. Save score with `StatisticManager.SetStatisticNumberData(user, leaderboardName, data)` and wait for `StatisticEventType.StatisticUpdateComplete` event from `DoWork`
3. Get the leaderboard with `StatisticManager.GetLeaderboard(user, leaderboardName, query)` and wait for `StatisticEventType.GetLeaderboardComplete` event from `DoWork`

On step 3 I get a C++ exception:

> “Not found (404)”.

[This looks very similar to this issue]([Exceptions and Error 404 when using StatsManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192320/exceptions-and-error-404-when-using-statsmanager)
).

So I’ve already checked the sandbox ID, config file and leaderboard ID but still get the same result.

I did capture the traffic from HTTP monitoring and I see URL like:

```
"https://leaderboards.xboxlive.com/scids/{scid}/leaderboards/stat({leaderboardId})?xuid={myXboxId}&maxItems=5"
```

Comment: Are those placeholders in the URL or the actual URL? I assume placeholder.

Comment: No, I see real SCID, LeaderboardID and Xbox User ID.

Comment: Is it possible saving the score fails? According to the source code of the SDK, 404 is returned if the leaderboard is empty https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-api/blob/c8461904ac389940c12b18c0473f65540bf69a1a/Include/xsapi/errors.h#L228

Comment: Possible. But shouldn't we get any error at step 2 then?

Comment: @MartinZikmund, I uploaded my game to the store and I checked that I can see the correct leaderboard in console menus so I think saving the score works perfectly.

Comment: @cherepets Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm getting this same error. Everything looks fine as Xbox Player is logged in (this would fail if the sand box id wasn't right) and I'm using my own Xbox Live account as a Test account.

Comment: @Dominique I did. By not using the SDK anymore ‍♂️

Comment: @Dominique Documentation says it's necessary to have the log in and select user functionality to pass the certification. But actually you can easily pass without it at all

Comment: @cherepets what did you use instead or did you give up on leaderboards?

Comment: @Dominique Yes, I've removed all Xbox Live related functionality.

Comment: @Dominique May be it's possible to use own leaderboards server. But I didn't try as it's not that important for my game.

Comment: @cherepets I had considered it. I just wish things that Microsoft say work, would just work. It would make dev so much simpler. Native leaderboards JUST work on iOS! I've had 2 tickets outstanding on this Xbox leaderboard issue for 6 months now and 2 weeks ago, XboxSupport, on Twitter, told me to log a NEW ticket!!  Absolute shambles!

Comment: XBOX live is dead. Long live XBOX. Not helpful due to obsolescence.

Answer (score 0):

under development, you *must* change your Xbox SANDBOX from RETAIL to {your sandbox} using XboxLiveTools (you can find it in github).
after published you can switch it back to RETAIL,and if there is no data in leaderboard return result with zero row no exception throw

I fixed the same problem by myself